# Human Written date from NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

What's the best way to convert something like this (Written to be easily read for humans):

`Jun 14, 2013` or another `Sep 23, 2009`

from an NSString into an NSDate?

I could only find ways to convert if the NSString was written in a more standard format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can Convert `NSString` Date to `NSDate` like following:

```
      NSString *str1 =@"Jun 14, 2013";
      NSString *str2;

      NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [df setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
      NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString: str1];

      str2=[df stringFromDate:myDate];

      NSDate *myDate2 = [df dateFromString: str2];

      // OUTPUT as your string 
      NSLog(@"same as your string %@",str2);

      // Here you can change date format that you want from actual formatted string.
      [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMM, dd"]; 

      //Out Put with change Format like 2013 Jun, 14
      NSLog(@"diffrent formate %@",[df stringFromDate:myDate2]);
```

Do not `NSLog` with `NSDate` object that show wrong that's why i put `NSlog` with str2

> The NSDate doesn't know anything about formatting (just date information), and the NSDateFormatter doesnt really know anything about dates, just how to format them. So you have to use methods like -stringFromDate: for know that is current or not to actually format the date for pretty human-readable display.